# How can I pass on a value in the hierarchy based on the value of the parent using an hierarchial query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, hierarchy

I have a table with categories and another table with a discount for categories per user:

```
create table category
( 
  id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  parent_id NUMBER,
  name nvarchar2(255),
  PRIMARY KEY( id)
);

create table category_discount
( 
  user_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  category_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  discount NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY( user_id, category_id)
);

insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 1, null, 'root');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 2, 1, 'C1');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 11, 7, 'C11');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 12, 7, 'C12');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 3, 1, 'C3');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 4, 1, 'C4');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 5, 4, 'C5');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 6, 4, 'C6');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 9, 6, 'C9');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 10, 6, 'C10');
insert into category( id, parent_id, name ) VALUES( 7, 1, 'C7');


insert into category_discount( user_id, category_id, discount ) VALUES( 1, 1, 30);
insert into category_discount( user_id, category_id, discount ) VALUES( 1, 4, 20);
insert into category_discount( user_id, category_id, discount ) VALUES( 1, 7, 25);
```

Now when I do this query:

```
SELECT category.*, 
       category_discount.user_id, 
       category_discount.discount, 
       LEVEL 
FROM   category
LEFT JOIN category_discount 
       ON category.id = category_discount.category_id 
       AND category_discount.user_id = 1
START WITH parent_id is null
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id;
```

...I get this output which is fine:

```
| ID | PARENT_ID | NAME | USER_ID | DISCOUNT | LEVEL |
|----|-----------|------|---------|----------|-------|
|  1 |    (null) | root |       1 |       30 |     1 |
|  2 |         1 |   C1 |  (null) |   (null) |     2 |
|  3 |         1 |   C3 |  (null) |   (null) |     2 |
|  4 |         1 |   C4 |       1 |       20 |     2 |
|  5 |         4 |   C5 |  (null) |   (null) |     3 |
|  6 |         4 |   C6 |  (null) |   (null) |     3 |
|  9 |         6 |   C9 |  (null) |   (null) |     4 |
| 10 |         6 |  C10 |  (null) |   (null) |     4 |
|  7 |         1 |   C7 |  (null) |   25     |     2 |
| 11 |         7 |  C11 |  (null) |   (null) |     3 |
| 12 |         7 |  C12 |  (null) |   (null) |     3 |
```

My requirement is whenever there is a discount on the parent it should be inherited down the hierarchy as long as the child doesn't haven an explicit discount set. So my final output should look like this:

```
| ID | PARENT_ID | NAME | USER_ID | DISCOUNT | LEVEL |
|----|-----------|------|---------|----------|-------|
|  1 |    (null) | root |       1 |       30 |     1 |
|  2 |         1 |   C1 |  (null) |       30 |     2 |
|  3 |         1 |   C3 |  (null) |       30 |     2 |
|  4 |         1 |   C4 |       1 |       20 |     2 |
|  5 |         4 |   C5 |  (null) |       20 |     3 |
|  6 |         4 |   C6 |  (null) |       20 |     3 |
|  9 |         6 |   C9 |  (null) |       20 |     4 |
| 10 |         6 |  C10 |  (null) |       20 |     4 |
|  7 |         1 |   C7 |  (null) |       25 |     2 |
| 11 |         7 |  C11 |  (null) |       25 |     3 |
| 12 |         7 |  C12 |  (null) |       25 |     3 |
```

How can I do this?

I am using Oracle 11g and Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without using [recursive subquery factoring](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2), with the magic of [`SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions183.htm#SQLRF06116):

> ```
> SELECT category.*, 
>        category_discount.user_id, 
>        category_discount.discount, 
>        sys_connect_by_path(category_discount.discount,':') discount_path, 
>        regexp_substr(rtrim(sys_connect_by_path(category_discount.discount,':'),':'),'[0-9]+$') actual_discount, 
>        LEVEL 
> FROM   category
> LEFT JOIN category_discount 
>        ON category.id = category_discount.category_id 
>        AND category_discount.user_id = 1
> START WITH parent_id is null
> CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | PARENT_ID | NAME | USER_ID | DISCOUNT | DISCOUNT_PATH | ACTUAL_DISCOUNT | LEVEL
> -: | --------: | :--- | ------: | -------: | :------------ | :-------------- | ----:
>  1 |      null | root |       1 |       30 | :30           | 30              |     1
>  2 |         1 | C1   |    null |     null | :30:          | 30              |     2
>  3 |         1 | C3   |    null |     null | :30:          | 30              |     2
>  4 |         1 | C4   |       1 |       20 | :30:20        | 20              |     2
>  5 |         4 | C5   |    null |     null | :30:20:       | 20              |     3
>  6 |         4 | C6   |    null |     null | :30:20:       | 20              |     3
>  9 |         6 | C9   |    null |     null | :30:20::      | 20              |     4
> 10 |         6 | C10  |    null |     null | :30:20::      | 20              |     4
>  7 |         1 | C7   |       1 |       25 | :30:25        | 25              |     2
> 11 |         7 | C11  |    null |     null | :30:25:       | 25              |     3
> 12 |         7 | C12  |    null |     null | :30:25:       | 25              |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4e569ab346aa35098c111b084d2ee78f)*

The `DISCOUNT` and `DISCOUNT_PATH` columns in the output are only included to make it clearer how this works — `ACTUAL_DISCOUNT` is the one you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
with a (id, parent_id, name, user_id, discount, lvl) as
(
  select
    c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, cd.user_id, cd.discount, 1 as lvl from category c
  LEFT JOIN category_discount cd
       ON c.id = cd.category_id AND cd.user_id = 1
  where parent_id is null
  union all
  select
    c2.id, c2.parent_id, c2.name, cd.user_id, 
    nvl(cd.discount, a.discount),
    lvl + 1
  from category c2
  LEFT JOIN category_discount cd 
       ON c2.id = cd.category_id AND cd.user_id = 1
  join a on c2.parent_id = a.id
)
search depth first by id set dummy
select id, parent_id, name, user_id, discount, lvl from a;

        ID  PARENT_ID NAME    USER_ID   DISCOUNT        LVL
---------- ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1            root          1         30          1
         2          1 C1                      30          2
         3          1 C3                      30          2
         4          1 C4            1         20          2
         5          4 C5                      20          3
         6          4 C6                      20          3
         9          6 C9                      20          4
        10          6 C10                     20          4
         7          1 C7            1         25          2
        11          7 C11                     25          3
        12          7 C12                     25          3
```

*Answer to original question:*

Assuming the following based on your example data (but I am not sure this is what you want):

There is a discount for the whole branch defined by the root - I call this root_discount.

If a child (c1) has discount set, then that is the discount for that child.

If c2 is a child of c1, and c2 does not have discount set, then c2 inherits the discount of c1.

If c3 is a child of c2, and c3 does not have discount set, then c3 inherits the discount from the root (root_discount). This makes the discount 30 for rows with ID 9,10. Without this, it gets a lot simpler.

```
with a (id, parent_id, name, user_id, discount, prev_discount, root_discount, lvl) as
(
  select
    c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, cd.user_id, cd.discount, 1 as prev_discount,
    discount as root_discount, 1 as lvl 
  from category c
  LEFT JOIN category_discount cd
       ON c.id = cd.category_id AND cd.user_id = 1
  where parent_id is null
  union all
  select
    c2.id, c2.parent_id, c2.name, cd.user_id, 
    nvl(cd.discount, case when prev_discount = 1 then a.discount else root_discount end),
    case when cd.discount is not null then 1 else a.prev_discount - 1 end as prev_discount, 
    root_discount, lvl + 1
  from category c2
  LEFT JOIN category_discount cd
       ON c2.id = cd.category_id AND cd.user_id = 1
  join a on c2.parent_id = a.id
)
search depth first by id set dummy
select id, parent_id, name, user_id, discount, lvl from a;

        ID  PARENT_ID NAME    USER_ID   DISCOUNT        LVL
---------- ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1            root          1         30          1
         2          1 C1                      30          2
         3          1 C3                      30          2
         4          1 C4            1         20          2
         5          4 C5                      20          3
         6          4 C6                      20          3
         9          6 C9                      30          4
        10          6 C10                     30          4
         7          1 C7            1         25          2
        11          7 C11                     25          3
        12          7 C12                     25          3
```

Comment: What if there is no root discount? Its not mandatory. Root discount is only to set a predefined discount for all categories and to not have to define it for each level.

Comment: @Jay Before going to that: C11 and C12 gor their discount from their direct parent C7. C9 and C10 did not get their discount from direct parent C6, but the root. So what is the rule here?

Comment: C11 and C12 have parent_id=7. Catgeory(7) has discount 25 through the join

Comment: @Jay So what is the correct discount value for C9 and C10 and based on what?  C6(20)? C4(20)? C1(30)? Based on what you described, it should be 20, still, it is 30 in the expected output.

Comment: C9 and C10 have parent=6. ID=6 has no discount through join. ID=6 has parent=4. ID =4 has discount through join of 20. So the discount would be 20 due inheritance. Did i make a mistake in the model?

Comment: Yeah i made a mistake in the expected output. Seems right now?

Comment: Thx for your help Sir.

Comment: @Jay I added that version to the answer. What McNets posted originally was also correct.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a recursive solution, replacing discount NULL values in child rows by the value of the parent row.

```
WITH x (id, parent_id, name, user_id, discount)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, cd.user_id, cd.discount
    FROM   
        category c
    LEFT JOIN 
        category_discount cd
        ON c.id = cd.category_id 
        AND cd.user_id = 1
    WHERE
        c.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, cd.user_id, 
        CASE WHEN cd.discount IS NULL THEN x.discount ELSE cd.discount END discount
    FROM   
        x
    JOIN   
        category c
        ON c.parent_id = x.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        category_discount cd
        ON c.id = cd.category_id 
        AND cd.user_id = 1
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    parent_id, 
    name,
    user_id,
    discount
FROM   
    x;
```

> ```
> ID | PARENT_ID | NAME | USER_ID | DISCOUNT
> -: | --------: | :--- | ------: | -------:
>  1 |      null | root |       1 |       30
>  2 |         1 | C1   |    null |       30
>  3 |         1 | C3   |    null |       30
>  4 |         1 | C4   |       1 |       20
>  7 |         1 | C7   |       1 |       25
> 11 |         7 | C11  |    null |       25
> 12 |         7 | C12  |    null |       25
>  5 |         4 | C5   |    null |       20
>  6 |         4 | C6   |    null |       20
>  9 |         6 | C9   |    null |       20
> 10 |         6 | C10  |    null |       20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9bc668baf99823a7fdb870e6358ff47d)*

Comment: Nice thank you. Doest it work for any depth ? How can i parametarize the user_id so its notf fixed to 1?

Comment: Could you use a function and pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Would it also work if i would have many category trees ( with and ID for each ). Because each user has its own category tree and its own discount rules. The trees are saved in one table?

Comment: You should have a look at  @JackDouglas's answer, he is an Oracle pro guy and his answer deserve to be accepted more than mine. For the category question, let me suggest to create a new question, and add a link to this one referencing it as the original question.